# How to iterate in a list to find names and values with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm developing an MVC project with .net. I have a json like this and its very long

```
{
    credit_id: "57214f73c3a3681e800005f4",
    department: "Production",
    id: 84493,
    job: "Casting",
    name: "Mickie McGowan",
    profile_path: "/k7TjJBfINsg8vLQxJwos6XObAD6.jpg"
},
{
    credit_id: "572294979251413eac0007e2",
    department: "Art",
    id: 7927,
    job: "Art Direction",
    name: "Ricky Nierva",
    profile_path: null
},
{
    credit_id: "572297cdc3a3682d240008f9",
    department: "Visual Effects",
    id: 7894,
    job: "Visual Effects",
    name: "Jean-Claude Kalache",
    profile_path: null
},
```

I put that jason in a list called "directorsData.crew" I have to find the names which their departments are "Directing" and add them in a directors list. How can I do it with LINQ?

like this

```
var directorsData = (tmdbMovie)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<tmdbMovie>(findDirectors);

List<string> directors = new List<string>();
if (directorsData != null)
{
    if (directorsData.crew.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in directorsData.crew) 
        {
            var name = directorsData.crew. ===?
            directors.Add(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI when you deserialize, you don't need to type cast back to `tmdbMovie`, as you're using the generic `DeserializeObject<tbdmMovie>()`, which already returns this type :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Linq you can get all names as list which department is `Directing`

```
var nameList = directorsData.crew.Where(a =>a.department == "Directing")
                                 .Select(a => a.name).ToList();
```

also, you can remove type casting in deserialization

```
var directorsData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<tmdbMovie>(findDirectors);
```

Comment: so I guess I don't need the foreach then?

Answer (score 0):

This will return a collection of `tmdbMovie` classes that have the department equal to "Directing".

```
var directingCollection = directorsData.crew.Where(x => x.Department.Equals("Directing"));
```

If you want only the names, in a string collection, you can do the following:

```
var nameCollection = directorsData.crew.Where(x => x.Department.Equals("Directing"))
                                       .Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

If you would like to loop through all the names, you can do the following:

```
nameCollection.ForEach(x =>
{
    //X will be the string value of the name
    //Your code here
});
```